# Trouble with James mail server: some time email message can't be received from gmail

Tags: java, james

I configured Apache James server in my local machine then added domains & user and then configured it in thunderbird.

Then I tried to send an email from Gmail to apache James server and I am facing below issue like,
Sometimes mail sent successfully from Gmail to the James server, but sometimes it's failed to send an email.

I am getting this error in Gmail: Address not found Your message wasn't delivered to [email address] because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.
The response from the remote server was: 550 5.1.1 [email address] Recipient not found.

Anyone please help me on this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to open access for dangerous apps on [myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?)